# Breaking out of node.js then()s

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am running through a whole of externally brought in data and at certain points I need to break and end my then chain and just redirect the page.

I have something like this:

**Api file**

```
gamesApi.getAllResultsWithTeamInformation(passData)
    .then(gamesApi.filterPreviousResults)
    .then(gamesApi.checkIfWeHaveGamesToSaveToDB) //Break at if nothing to save
    .then(gamesApi.loopAndSaveToDB)
    .then(gamesApi.selectLatestLeagueID)
```

**Function where I want the break to happen**

```
checkIfWeHaveGamesToSaveToDB: function (passData) {
    if(passData.uniqueData.length === 0){
        passData.req.flash('notice', 'Sorry there was nothing new to save);
        passData.res.redirect('/admin/games/' + passata.leagueInfo.year);
        passData.res.end();
    }else {
        return passData;
    }
},
```

However when `passData.uniqueData.length === 0` is true, it will redirect the page, but the chain will carry on running. How can I break/stop if `passData.uniqueData.length === 0` is true?

Comment: How'd I do that :)? I'll google now though

Comment: return `Promise.reject('something')` or `throw something`

Comment: Ye thanks guys: `return Promise.reject();` I wonder though, its not an error so much. This will throw an error. I guess I need to catch it and not display an error.

Comment: If you are going to use promise rejection as a way to avoid fulfill handlers, do catch only the specific error and rethrow any other error. Otherwise, you'll get silent errors in any other step in the promise chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your checkIfWeHaveGamesToSaveToDB function as follows

```
checkIfWeHaveGamesToSaveToDB: function (passData) {
    if(passData.uniqueData.length === 0){
        passData.req.flash('notice', 'Sorry there was nothing new to save);
        passData.res.redirect('/admin/games/' + passata.leagueInfo.year);
        passData.res.end();
        // either
        return Promise.reject('nothing new to save'); 
        // or
        throw 'nothing new to save';
    }else {
        return passData;
    }
},
```

remember to add a `.catch` at the end of your "then" chain to handle the rejection properly (even do nothing)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use on of two possible solutions.

Solution 1: nest your Promise

```
sth
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.then((result) => {
  if (looksGood(result)) {
    return sth
      .then(sth)
      .then(sth)
      .then(sth)
  } else {
    // do nothing?
  }
})
```

Solution 2: Throw custom error

```
sth
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.then((result) => {
  if (looksGood(result)) {
    return result
  } else {
    throw new AbortError()
  }
})
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.then(sth)
.catch(...) // catch and ignore AbortError, rethrow anything else
```

I believe the pros&cons of both proposed solutions are pretty clear: Solution 1 looks ugly, Solution 2 misuses Error-throwing-mechanism - this is little controversial at least. Solution 2 can be done nicer by writing a few custom helpers for throwing / catching the AbortError.

My personal favorite is solution nr. 2: Having spent some time with Python, I don't see hacking with custom Exceptions as a necessarily bad idea.